# Avalonia UI Pop-Up Overlay

Tags: c#, reactiveui, avaloniaui

My question is pretty straight forward:

How do I achieve an Overlay Pop-Up effect using avalonia?

What I mean by this is I want to darken the whole Panel that contains my UI elements a little bit (tried the opacity attribute, but it didn't look good and the OpacityMask only seems to support "Transparent" as a color, but I want semi-transparency or even blur if that's possible). Then I want to display a little popup box. If this were CSS I'd be able to do a `position: absolute;`, however I couldn't figure out how to do this using avalonia.

To visualize what I mean here are some screenshots of a Windows Forms Application where I was able to achieve the desired effect:

My UI without overlay effect:
[image]

My UI with overlay effect:
[image]

As you can see the whole UI has been darkened a bit while the background is still visible (when using the avalonia `Opacity` property the effect is not the same and quite inconsistent, as the more panels are on top of each other on a given position the less the background seems to be affected by the `Opacity` and it just doesn't look good. I can add screenshots of how bad it would look later if you want.)

To sum it up:

**1. How do I slightly and consistently darken (or even blur?) a panel with all of its contents, so that stacked panels with the same background color don't become visible, just because the transparency is acting weird?**

**2. What is the avalonia equivalent to the CSS `position: absolute;` so I can put my Pop-Up in the middle of the screen and on top of everything else?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the same technique as in WPF:

```
<Window>
   <Grid>
      <DockPanel x:Name="YourMainContentGoesHere"/>
      <Border IsVisible="{Binding IsPopupVisible}" Background="#40000000">
          <YourPopupControlHere Width="200" Height="200"/>
      </Border>   
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Unconfigured `Grid` will display elements on top of each other, semi-transparent `Border`'s background will darken the rest of the content.

Comment: Wow, this is obvious when you think of it (everything will be on Row = 0, Column = 0 and thus overlayed). Elegant!