# How to get the dimensions of an Avalonia window?

Tags: c#, avalonia

I'm creating a C# .NET Core 5 application that's intended to run on both windows 10 and Linux using Avalonia as a GUI. I don't want to use the reactive api. I couldn't find out how to use the notification system that avalonia supports so I decided to create a separate window which stays on top for X seconds and displays a title and a message. The window disappears after X seconds or sooner if the user clicks on it.

This is part of the code:

```
public class NotificationMessage : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    
    public string NMessage { get; set; }
    public string NTitle { get; set; }

    public NotificationMessage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    
    public NotificationMessage(string title, string message, int Xparent, int Yparent, int time)
    {
        DataContext = this;
        NMessage = message;
        NTitle = title;
        Timer timer = new Timer(time);
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Elapsed += OnTime;
        timer.Start();
        double height = this.Height;
        double width = this.ClientSize.Width;
        double sum = height + width; // this line was added just to insert a breakpoint
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{this.Bounds.Width}-{this.Bounds.Height}");
    }

    private void OnTime(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        
        Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => { this.Close(); });
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }

    private void Tapped(object sender, Avalonia.Interactivity.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

The window is called like this:

```
XScreenSize = Screens.Primary.WorkingArea.Width;
YScreenSize = Screens.Primary.WorkingArea.Height;
var win = new NotificationMessage("my title", "my message", XScreenSize, YScreenSize, 3000);
win.Show(this);
```

'this' refers to the MainWindow.

`XScreenSize` and `YScreenSize` get the size of the screen.
I've tried to get the size of the notification window in order to calculate its placement but it seems impossible to me.
`win.Height` returns NaN (the same applies for `win.Width`)
`win.Bounds` does not help either.
The same for `win.ClientSize`.
I've tried every property that seemed relevant to me but I can't get the size of the new window.
Is there any way to do so that will work in both OS?

I suppose it should be obvious but I'm adding the xaml file for the notification window as well:

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             x:Class="NotificationMessage" HasSystemDecorations="False" CanResize="False" 
        Tapped="Tapped" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" FontSize="16" Topmost="True">
  <Border BorderThickness="2">
    <DockPanel Background="DodgerBlue" Margin="2,2,2,2">

      <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding NTitle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Medium" />

      <TextBlock Text="{Binding NMessage}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Opacity=".8" Margin="2,2,2,2"/>

    </DockPanel>
  </Border>

</Window>
```

Comment: The `Window.ShowDialog` method does very similar thing, what's your research on it?

Comment: The ShowDialog will block the parent window

Comment: I mean how it works under the hood.

Comment: @ShadowsInRain: I don't know. You'll have to close the dialog before proceeding with anything else. I don't want that. I just want to notify the user that something happened without preventing the user from interacting with the main window.

Comment: Avalonia is an open-source software, you can literally see its source code: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Controls/Window.cs — search for `ShowDialog`. On other hand, using windows for simple pop-up message may be an overkill, you could try an overlay instead —  see https://stackoverflow.com/q/62194012/1125702

Comment: @ShadowsInRain: I know I can see the code but I just need to get the size of the window! I don't have the time to check the code to see what's going on behind the scenes and then perhaps I might get what I want. My code is almost ready. The pop-up link is not what I was looking for. Thanks anyway...